# Test void method using mokito

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

How do I test below method using mockito

```
public void showArg(String ss) {
    if(ss == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }else if(ss.equals("")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    // Log.d("",""+ss);
    if(ss.equals("xyz")) {
        this.show();
    }else {
        getResult(0);
    }
}
```

In this example, there is nothing to be mocked. I just want to test the that is appropriate methods are called based on i/p.

Comment: @Denny : I am calling method showArg("xyz"), But how do I test that after calling his method show() is getting called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to verify that this method was called (assuming it was public), I suggest using a spy...

```
MyClass spy = Mockito.spy( myActualObject );
spy.showArg("xyz");
Mockito.verify(spy).show();
```

Spying (instead of mocking) means to take an actual object and "spy" on it, by wrapping it in another instance. This way you can call actual methods, but also check what was called and even modify what some methods will do, similar to mocking (the difference is, that a mock does not have an underlying "real" object, while a spy has).

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned you should use a spy to test such code. Additionaly looking at your code you should also test whether appropiate exceptions are thrown.

Code testing border cases can be looking like this:

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void shouldThrowNullPointerExceptionWhenNullStringProvided() {
    showArg(null);
}

@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void shouldThrowIllegarArgumentExceptionWhenEmptyStringProvided() {
    showArg("");
}
```